# How to do Postgresql 9.2 version check in Linux?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2, startup

```
$ systemctl restart postgresql-9.2.24

Failed to restart postgresql-9.2.24.service: Unit not found.
```

Comment: Check out the `whereis`, `which` and `apropos` commands.

Comment: The service name typically does not include the minor version. So the name would be `postgresql-9.2.service` (btw: Postgres 9.2 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run:

```
systemctl  | grep postgres
```

... and you'll be able to see what the service is actually called.

For example:

```
phil@ironforge:~/M$ systemctl  | grep postgr
  postgresql.service                                                loaded active exited    PostgreSQL RDBMS
  postgresql@9.3-main.service                                       loaded active running   PostgreSQL Cluster 9.3-main
  postgresql@9.5-main.service                                       loaded active running   PostgreSQL Cluster 9.5-main
  system-postgresql.slice                                           loaded active active    system-postgresql.slice
phil@ironforge:~/M$
```

So, in this case, I can just use:

```
systemctl restart postgresql
```

eg:

```
phil@ironforge:~/M$ systemctl restart postgresql
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units ===
Authentication is required to restart 'postgresql.service'.
Authenticating as: root
Password: *******
==== AUTHENTICATION COMPLETE ===
phil@ironforge:~/M$
```

Comment: This works fine. thanks yaar. happy coding !

Answer (score 1):

That means that there is no file named

```
postgresql-9.2.24.service
```

in your `systemd` directory.

The exact location varies between Linux distributions, but it is usually `/usr/lib/systemd/system` or `/lib/systemd/system`.